# twitter API 1.1: cannot add the 'count' parameter using curl & php

Tags: php, json, api, curl, twitter

I'm connecting to the new twitter API to get a list of my profiles' public tweets.
I'm basically using the following code, which I found here: [Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1)

I'm getting the last 20 tweets and I've tried many different ways to add the "count" parameter to the curl call, but nothing seems to return more results.

I tried giving a value to the $postfields:

```
$postfields = array(
        'count' => 100,
        'include_rts' => 1
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($postfields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Giving a simple string value:

```
§postfields = 'count=100';
```

and changing the $url value into:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=100";
```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks for your help!!

This is the complete code for reference:

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
ksort($params);
foreach($params as $key=>$value){
    $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
}
return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
$r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
$values = array();
foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
$r .= implode(', ', $values);
return $r;
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$oauth_access_token = "YOURVALUE";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "YOURVALUE";
$consumer_key = "YOURVALUE";
$consumer_secret = "YOURVALUE";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce' => time(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0');



$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' .     rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;



$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
              //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
              CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);



$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);
$twitter_data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: so when I use $postfields = array ('count' => '100') as the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS parameter I get a 32 code error from twitter. When I disable the $postfields, I get my last 20 tweets. Any clues?

Answer (score -1):

```
$items = '15';
$screen_name = 'YOUR SCREEN NAME';
/* the $oauth */
$oauth = array(
        'screen_name' => $screen_name,
        'count' => $items,
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce' => time(),
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' .     rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;



$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?screen_name='.$screen_name.'&count='.$items,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);
```