# Twitter API Version 1.1 with Styling

Tags: php, api, twitter, styling

I wish to create a twitter feed on a website I am writing, and having not had much luck browsing the documentation on the twitter website, I have come across [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1). In particular I was looking at the code posted by rivers, this seems to get the tweets but I am not clear of the correct way to display them and does anyone know if twitter provide any style sheets for presentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [display guidelines](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements) are as close as you're going to get to a "style sheet" for presentation. A "style sheet" wouldn't do you just a ton of good anyways, as you're going to need to construct your own HTML output mirroring what the style sheet is meant to style for them to be of any use.

It's hard to give you much direction since it isn't clear what you're really shooting for, but [embedded tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) or [embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) may be closer to what you're looking for.