# add name to coordinates for directions with google sdk in io6

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

How can i redirect my app to the google maps app and provide a title for the coordinates i want the directions for. below code works fine if i leave out ",+MYNAME". But only giving the coordinates do not look friendly. 
I want to for example put "Private parking" as MYNAME. But if i put it at the beginning google looks for the first directions it can find for "private parking" and ignores the coordinates. If i put it second (like below) it cannot interpretate the direction.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:
 @"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=MYLATITUDE,MYLONGITUDE,+MYNAME&directionsmode=driving"
 ]];
```

How can i just add a name/title to my coordinates?

Comment: Could you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1?lq=1#comment24745003_12916539) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1?lq=1#comment24932691_12939923)? I see you online all the time, probably just after that 100 days badge ;) but would very much appreciate a response!