# Is this Twitter Search API code Deprecated?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm new to the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) and was wondering whether my code snippet below is deprecated?

```
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3astackexchange'));
```

If so, can you give me an example of a version that is not deprecated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it is?

Comment: +1 In the top right hand corner of the Twitter Search API page, they state version 1 (which is deprecated) and version 1.1 (which is not). So that confused me as to whether I'm looking at code that may be deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [this code is deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search).

The manual page links to the [Twitter API v1.1 version](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets).

Comment: +1 I was afraid of that. Hmmmm, so what is the alternative? Is it much more difficult? Requires oath?

Comment: I see authentication is required for 1.1 version. Can you recommend a good tutorial on how to use this?

Comment: There's some good sample code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1).