# How to get results with twitter search api?

Tags: twitter

I wish to get tweets with a keyword. But There is no result with any keyword.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=summer

How to get results with Twitter Search API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 1 of the twitter API has been deprecated and is **being removed**. Not sure how you can miss the giant warnings on the twitter dev site ;) This means simple code like the above *will not work any more*.

So, you now need to make authenticated requests (OAuth) using the 1.1 API, and it's nowhere near as simple as just doing a (in PHP) `file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/ ...)`.

I couldn't see any server-side languages you use from your profile, but I wrote a [lengthy post explaining the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) (with pictures) and how to use a [php](/questions/tagged/php) library to perform authenticated requests.