# Tweepy API search method not working

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to access the search feature of the twitter api through a python wrapper for the api named tweepy. I have the following code:

```
import tweepy as t

auth = t.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token_key,access_token_secret)
api = t.API(auth)
api.search(q='#somepopularhashtag')
```

The output that I receive is an empty list as opposed to a list of twitter.status objects supposed to be returned. Could anyone help me out with this problem. I am using tweepy 2.0

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968080/twitter-search-query-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not related to `tweepy` itself. Twitter has some problems with search API (basically it doesn't work) right now, see relevant issues and discussions:

- https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1072
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18312
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18319

See also relevant discussions on SO:

- [How to get results with twitter search api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954560/how-to-get-results-with-twitter-search-api)
- [Twitter Search API no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969076/twitter-search-api-no-results)
- [Twitter Search API Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957749/twitter-search-api-php)

Plus, I'm not sure that `tweepy` migrated to twitter API [1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) completely (see [open issues](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues) on the project).

UPD:

Upgrade `tweepy` to the latest version directly from the github:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I still don't know what the issue was but I am using python-twitter another python wrapper around the twitter api. I basically created a new app as I had not used my old twitter app for a while and hence I am assuming the access_token and access_token_secret were not accepted, but the thing is that OAuth went through perfectly even with the old access_token and secret. I still have no clue what happened but like I said my solution was to switch to python-twitter and create a fresh twitter app and use the new tokens and secrets provided.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Can you please check if tweepy now works with your new access token and secret?

Comment: well yes Tweepy works (meaning the get_user and get_friends etc... work fine) but the search method still does not work.

Comment: @user1009091 upgrade to the latest tweepy version directly from github: `git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git` and `python setup.py install` - should fix the search problem. Then, consider accepting the answer. Thanks.