# Twitter Search API Php

Tags: twitter

I am facing a problem in twitter api.

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=test&rpp=5&include_entities=1

I have used the above URL for getting the tweets for the given query. It worked well until yesterday. But now I have checked, this is returning empty result set.

I have surfed through the twitter api and I can't able to find the relevant api method. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Twitter api should not be updated till 12the of June. Hope this question gets the right awnser

Comment: Any alternative method available for this functionality?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the API for your support options first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your Issue

There's a [bug reported here](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1072) that corresponds with the issue you're having.

### 5 days

You literally have **five days** until unauthenticated requests will not function **at all** any more.

[image]

You now need to make authenticated requests (OAuth) using the 1.1 API, and it's nowhere near as simple as just doing a (in PHP) `file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/ ...)`.

Version 1 of the twitter API has been deprecated and is being removed. Not sure how you can miss the giant warnings on the twitter dev site ;) This means simple code like the above **will not work any more**.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) on how to make authenticated requests using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You use a deprecated API (1.0), Twitter is shutting down this one and moving to 1.1.
see here:[Twitter API 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)