# Twitter Search API no results

Tags: php, twitter

I have a PHP script that uses the Twitter Search API to find tweets matching a search but for some reason is no longer working and is not returning any results.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

```
<?php   

$search=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode($_GET[q]).'%20vine.co%2Fv%2F&result_type=recent&include_entities=1&rpp=9&page='.$_GET[page]));
foreach($search->results as $result){
 foreach($result->entities->urls as $url){
   echo $url->expanded_url;
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: change `$_GET[q]` to `$_GET['q']` , and also `$_GET['page']`

Comment: @karthikr This has nothing to do with it. The API isn't returning any results for some reason.

Comment: @karthikr without that changes it would still work as it should. But doing that is better a habit.

Comment: Have you done `print_r($search)`? Have you looked up for SearchAPI in twitter if that has changed in the meantime or not?

Comment: @Lenin I have done both. `print_r($search)` seems empty and I did a quick search but I'm not sure. It may have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Bug

There's currently a bug in the 1.0 API - see **[this bug report](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1072)**. Anyway, unauthenticated requests will *stop working in four days*.

### Deprecated (and retired) 1.0 API

Twitter requires you to use **authenticated requests** (OAuth) because, five days from now, the v1.0 API will be **removed completely**.

What this means for you is that a simple:

```
file_get_contents( . . . )
```

... well, for the 1.0 api, it'll just stop returning data! Five days from now, you won't be able to use that any more!

See [this post I posted today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957749/twitter-search-api-php/16960422#16960422) for a little background information and proof of the API removal date (five days from now).

See **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)** for a walk through of how to make authenticated requests using Twitter's 1.1 API. It's pretty simple if you use [this library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and only a few lines of code to make the actual request.