# how to post tweet using twitter 1.1 api and twitteroauth

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I use the below code to retrieve my tweets and echo json. This works fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/twitter/twitteroauth.php');

$twitteruser = "xxxxxx";
$notweets = 3;
$consumerkey = "xxxxxxx";
$consumersecret = "xxxxxx";
$accesstoken = "xxxxxxxx";
$accesstokensecret = "xxxxxx";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret); 
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

 echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

Now i want to send a tweet using the similar code but it doesnot work. I am not sure if the sending syntax is correct. so please someone help me.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/twitter/twitteroauth.php'); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "xxxxxx";
$notweets = 3;
$consumerkey = "xxxxxxx";
$consumersecret = "xxxxxx";
$accesstoken = "xxxxxxxx";
$accesstokensecret = "xxxxxx";

// start connection
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
//message
$message = "Hi how are you";
//send message
$status = $connection->post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', array('status' => $message));
?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was using twitteroauth.php to post tweets myself when the new API broke it. You are using the `$connection->post` correctly, but it appears that function does not work anymore. The easiest solution I found was to swap out the twitteroauth.php with J7mbo's twitter-api-php file for the new 1.1 API:

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Here's his step-by-step instructions for using it. I think you'll be pleasantly surprised to find you can leave most of your code the same, just switch the twitteroauth calls with his function calls at the appropriate places:

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

He doesn't provide the specific example of posting a tweet, but here's what what you need for that function:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'; 
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$postfields = array(
    'status' => 'Hi how are you' ); 
echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->setPostfields($postfields)
             ->performRequest();
```

With the new twitter API, you won't need to provide your username/password. The authentication token will handle everything.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the example:

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' =>$message));
```

Comment: Do we get tweet id and time as a response?

Comment: I want to pass another 'url' parameter with 'status' is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Try it 
you won't need to username/password you can post via API key read the tutorial here.

http://designspicy.com/learn-how-to-post-on-twitter-using-php-and-oauth/

Answer (score -2):

The issue is about enconding the value need to be enconde :

Example

```
$status = $connection->post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', array('status' => rawurlencode($message)));
```

If you check in the library recomended https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

That the way they encode the params