# php to twitter api 1.1request url

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to post from php to twitter using api 1.1. I have followed this post:

[how to post tweet using twitter 1.1 api and twitteroauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064834/how-to-post-tweet-using-twitter-1-1-api-and-twitteroauth)

and it's step by step link solution

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

but nothing happens. Should I change the **REQUEST SETTINGS** in the **OAUTH TOOL** tab to

**request url: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json**

**request type: post**

and if so how do you do this? There seems to be no way to update this from the current

https://api.twitter.com/1/

get

[image]

here is the code for the post:

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
 /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
  $settings = array(
  'oauth_access_token' => "",
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
  'consumer_key' => "",
  'consumer_secret' => ""
);


  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'; 
  $requestMethod = 'POST';


$postfields = array('status' => 'Hi This is a post' ); 

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

 echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->setPostfields($postfields)
         ->performRequest();
```

This is as suggested in the link. I have of course added the relevant codes -tokens and secrets.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might be a daft question, but you are setting the values in $settings? You've just not put them in your question here - right?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant by - I have of course added the relevant codes.

Comment: What's the result of calling that function, i.e. which is the error? Do you have, for instance, cURL installed?

Comment: I have the TwitterApiExchange.php, which is part of this [link]https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php . There is no error just a blank document.

Comment: No-one seems interested in this. Does everyone have it working?