# Twitter request to get the latest tweets for a hashtag using Twitter API V1.1 using OAuth settings

Tags: twitter, tweets

Can any one explain how to send a Twitter request to get the latest tweets for a `hashtag` using Twitter API V1.1 using `OAuth` settings ? I have searched for documentation in Twitter site, but I am incomplete.

Can any one give the sample request & response through `RestClient` or `Advanced Rest Client` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jimbo, Thanks for the detailed explanation and providing appropriate links..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have multiple questions here, so I'll answer them one by one.

**The search/tweets method**

You can search tweets using [this method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) in the 1.1 API. According to those docs, you can pass a `q` parameter which is "a UTF-8 encoded query of 1000 characters maximum".

**The query for your specific requirements**

Scroll down on [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) and you'll see that you can search for a specific hashtag using `#hashtag`. Yes, that's it.

**How can I make V1.1 requests using OAuth?**

Follow the detailed step-by-step post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662), using [this library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) to make authenticated requests.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I make REST calls using Java, is there any example for that. Also can you please help me with this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170302/how-to-get-the-top-tweets-for-the-given-trend-in-twitter