# Twitter api 1.1, get ALL tweets by hashtag search /search/tweets.json limits

Tags: php, symfony, twitter

I know how to get tweets from a hashtag ([Twitter request to get the latest tweets for a hashtag using Twitter API V1.1 using OAuth settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087732/twitter-request-to-get-the-latest-tweets-for-a-hashtag-using-twitter-api-v1-1-us))

But it appears that some tweets associated with a hashtag aren't retrieved, even with the parameter "recent". And if I tweet on #somethingforexample, there isn't a tweet with the api for that same hashtag.

On https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets : 
"Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface."

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to get the [twitter firehose](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2752). Right now you get a subset of the tweets that twitter makes available.

If you have an exhaustive list of your sources (twitter ID or screen_name) you may poll their tweets directly following the rate limit guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't need real-time access but just execute a cron task that get the 50 most recent tweets and store them in a database and execute that 1/week maybe. I still need firehose ? Firehose is for all public tweets, and I only need search for a hashtag.

Comment: I was going by the title '..get ALL tweets..' and didn't understand fully. I'm not sure there is a way to get all recent tweets for a hashtag. IIUC, twitter provides a subset via the search APIs so you'll be able to fetch the top 50 that they match for any given search but there is no guarantee that the results will be exhaustive (without actually having access to the firehose).