# How to retrieve hashtaged tweets from a list of users

Tags: twitter

Is there a way retrieving all the tweets from a list of profiles (3) which are tagged with certain #hashtag in a single call to the Twitter API using 1.1?

If not, obviously, I'd be retrieving a hundred tweets from each user, and filtering out those which do not have the #hashtag .. but it's not very efficient, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, I've found I can filter my call so I can retrieve #hashtag messages from a twitter user like this: 
[link]https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23YourHashtag%20from:TwitterUserHandle&result_type=recent&count=25'

But is there a way of sending several users to the call?

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't be very efficient. Do as much filtering on their servers as you can before the data is returned to your own server.

Comment: I'm actually using your TwitterAPIExchange.php proxy OAuth to make the calls. Thanks for that, btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Note:** I've updated [the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) so I suggest you grab the newly updated version before trying this - I've made it so you don't need to manually encode each individual character.

[This page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) shows you how to use search, and has a number of operators down toward the bottom of the page. One of these is the `OR` operator:

## Getting tweets for multiple users

**OR** - Either this *or* that

`love OR hate - containing either "love" or "hate" (or both)`

**From** - From this user

`from:twitterapi    sent from the user @twitterapi`

So, armed with the above knowledge, I'm *guessing* your query would look like this:

**Translated into a GET request:**

`?q=from:user1+OR+from:user2`

---

## Getting tweets for specific hashtags

So that's how you get tweets for multiple users. The next step you want is for certain hashtags.

`#haiku - containing the hashtag "haiku"`

That translated individually into the correct format becomes:

`?#haiku` *(or %2C haiku, depending on the library / urlencoding you're using)*

---

## Combining the above

The standard AND operator looks like this:

`twitter search - containing both "twitter" and "search". Default operator`

For a get request:

`?twitter+search`

So let's combine all this!

`?q=#hashtag1+#hashtag2+from:user1+OR+from:user2`

And, because you're using [my lib](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php), here's the code for that:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$getfield = '?q=#hashtag1+OR+#hashtag2+from:username1+OR+from:username2';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json =  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                 ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jimbo!! Appreciate the effort .. will try this asap!

Comment: Thanks a bunch. :)