# twitter api (php) - statuses/destroy - returns nothing

Tags: php, twitter

I am using the tmOAuth library.

With the new 1.1 API, the following is returning an error code 400 - but authentication was done (same authentication for statuses works)! The library I am using works fine for all calls, except this one!

```
$tmhOAuth->request(
    'POST', $tmhOAuth->url('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/MYIDHERE.json'),
    array(
        'id' => MYIDHERE
    )
);
```

The twitter API documentation states that you don't have to send the id in post - but this doesn't make any difference.

I have tested this today with two different libraries, and neither work.

Any suggestions - does anyone know if there is an issue with it??

Comment: Submit a bug report to the vendor on github, on the 'issues' tab.

Comment: tested now in 2 api - can't be a simple api error

Comment: Andi, it's a library issue - the ones you've tested with do not work. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164829/twitter-api-php-statuses-destory-returns-nothing/17168356#comment24855777_17164829), you have tested this in two libraries for the **1.1 API**.

You haven't tested it in [this one](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) though. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662), although you seem to already have your credentials in hand.

This basically proves that the library you are using has the issue, not the twitter API. So either submit a bug report on github (how else are they to know?), or use another library like the one above.

The exact code required using the above library (**and it works, I just tested it**):

```
// Require the library file
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

// Set up your credentials
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_TOKEN",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET",
    'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
    'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
);

// Put the correct ID in the URL
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/YOURIDHERE.json';

// Set the request type
$requestMethod = 'POST';

// Set the post fields
$postfields = array('id' => 'YOURIDHERE');

// Make the request
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json =  $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->setPostfields($postfields)
                 ->performRequest();

// Dump the response
$result = json_decode($json);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Perfect - your right - it worked as it should. ;) safed me some more hours from figuring out the error!!

Comment: Maybe `$postfields` is not required : all the info is in the url.

Comment: @Asenar If all the info is in the url, then it's a GET request. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the twitteroauth php library from Abraham Williams and trying to delete old tweets/retweets you need to construct the `post()` query as such:

```
$response = $connection->post('statuses/destroy/'.$tweetID, array()); //Curl url output = statuses/destroy/$tweetID.json
```