# Testing Twitter API 1.1 locally?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I've got a website that uses the old Twitter 1.0 API, which was deprecated a few days ago and no longer works. I'm in the process of trying to update it to use v 1.1 instead.

Unfortunately it would appear that Twitter wants authentication for everything, I can no longer just dump in a JavaScript plugin that will do the work for me, I have to set up an application and pass various keys - this isn't too much of a problem, but I'm trying to test it locally and have no idea how to go about this.

When setting up an application with Twitter (which I understand is necessary for using their API) I have to input a Website, what do I put in here (IP addresses are not accepted)?

Is it the case that I have to use a Proxy to test locally? The site uses Wordpress but I can't seem to find any plugins that don't require application keys.

In Short, how do I use the Twitter 1.1 API in a local development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we're on the same page, when you say "twitter requires a website", you mean this when creating a new application:

[image: Random fields that can be anything]

Okay, so it **doesn't matter** what website and other settings you put in the twitter dev site. The point of it is that you're getting a **unique set of keys** that will go between you and twitter to authenticate you. That's it!

If you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662), it'll explain a bit more.

As for doing things in the "local development environment" - if you follow the above post, you can just do it all within an index.php file in `/var/www` or wherever, it doesn't matter. It's effectively just a script, a single php file that you include. You then create a new object using it and run a few methods, it's very simple. You don't need a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly what I needed to get it working. A lot simpler than I imagined it to be!