# How to get twitter feed from twitter API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I have two online banner (flash and HTML5) using twitter feed when API 1.0 . 
We know that API 1.0 can get the feed by a URL directly. 
(Just like: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/annrubin.json?count=3)

How can I get the feed like XML format? Because flash banner is difficult to use HTML code.

Comment: did my post help, did you find a solution?

Comment: Still trying. But I don't know how to authenticate in Flash.
For HTML5, I follow "Embedded Timelines" and success to add a timeline in the banner. But I can't remove the "Retweeted" data.

Comment: So, if my answer was correct / helped? could you upvote / tick? If not, might as well delete it because it didn't help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the **1.1** version of the API. It's been plastered all over the [API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) for months that the 1.0 API (the one you're currently using) is being removed.

Also, the twitter API **no longer returns XML format**. They made the good decision to return all data in **JSON**. From the [FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#10648):

> API v1.1 will support JSON only. We’ve been hinting at this for some time now, first dropping XML support on the Streaming API and more recently on the trends API. XML, Atom, and RSS are infrequently used today, and we’ve chosen to throw our support behind the JSON format shared across the platform. Consequently, we’ve decided to discontinue support for these other formats.

You can't make client-side (JS / jQuery / AJAX) requests to the twitter API any more as of 11th June 2013. You need to pick up a server-side language to make authenticated requests (if you choose PHP, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)).

Comment: Hi Jimbo, thanks for your reply.
Actually I have try the [ https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=IBMSmarterMktg&count=2 ] but it have error 215. So how to get the data?

Comment: @KasaYiu All requests **must be authenticated**. This means you **must** follow the steps in the post above. You can't just type that URL into the address bar any more. It won't work.