# Is there a way to get a list of users based on a hashtag they used?

Tags: twitter

I want to get a list of users who have used a particular hashtag. Eg. #ManOfSteel.

How can I get a list of the users who are using that hashtag as well as their details (like which city they are tweeting from) using a twitter API or any other means?

Comment: -could you 'tick' an answer to mark it as correct, if it was useful? Else I'll delete.. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. And it's quite simple, really.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets):

> **GET search/tweets:** - Returns a collection of relevant Tweets matching a specified query.
>
> **Resource URL:** https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

Now if you scroll down on that page, it gives an example of what a query for a tweet returns (I took a screen, sorry about the appalling arrow, it's 10am here and I haven't had my tea yet).

[image: Awesome arrow diagram]

Great! So you know the URL and method (GET) that you need to get your data. As for searching for a hashtag specifically, the [query documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) is what you're after.

This is basically as urlencoded string in the GET request like: `?q=#hashtag`. Perform the search like that and you'll get back the data above. Then just loop through it, find the user object, and grab the value `location` key if you want the user's city.

---

Now, as for a **library** to interact with the twitter API, you haven't even stated what language you're using. From your profile, you use JAVA I'm guessing. Regardless, checkout the [libraries page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) on the twitter dev site - there's one for JAVA that looks pretty good (and many for other languages too).

If you were using [php](/questions/tagged/php), [this post would be immensely helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662).