# Reading twitter feed using api 1.1 from c#

Tags: c#, twitter

Ok. I thought I would fix this rather easy, but I'm not getting anything to work for some reason. What I want to do is simple; I want to create a web part displaying the latest tweets from a specific user. I'm coding C#.

I found a great post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1) but it's using php.

Can anyone help me to perform this simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find alot examples over internet

Web:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/learning-the-basics-of-using-the-twitter-api-in-aspnet-web-pages-with-razor-syntax

Console:

http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/13/A-Simple-Twitter-Client-in-C-with-OAUTH-using-TweetSharp.aspx

:)

Comment: Thanks! Your links got me in the right direction. It turned out my code couldn't handle ssl, so I needed a little tweak to get around it.