# PHP mysql Twitter API 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter, cron

```
<?php
    function saveTweets($screen_name) {
        $db = array("h"=>"localhost", "u"=>"user", "p"=>"pass", "n"=>"db");
        $dbconnect = mysql_connect($db['h'], $db['u'], $db['p']);
        $dbselect = mysql_select_db($db['n']); 
        $screen_name = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($screen_name)));
        if (!$screen_name) {
            echo "<p><strong>Error: No screen name declared.</strong></p>\n"; return false;
        }
        $row = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `twitter` WHERE `screen_name`='$screen_name' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($row);
        $last_id = $row['id'];
        $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=$screen_name" ;
        if ($last_id) {
            $url .= "&since_id=$last_id" ;
        }
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $xml = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $affected = 0;
        $twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        foreach ($twelement->status as $status) {
            $text = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($status->text));
            $time = strtotime($status->created_at);
            $id = $status->id;
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `twitter` (`id`,`screen_name`,`time`,`text`,`hidden`) VALUES ('$id','$screen_name','$time','$text','n')");
            $affected = $affected + mysql_affected_rows();
        }
    return "<p>".number_format($affected)." new tweets from $screen_name saved.</p>\n" ;
    }
    echo saveTweets('screenName');
?>
```

I am trying to use this script to grab from my twitter feed. But it returns 0 new tweets saved from 'screenName'. Does anyone can help please?

Note: I actually replaced the screenName with many account of mine and my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After retirement of twitter api 1.0 , now almost everything data come from twitter is by authentication. you can read all details through below link
[Twitter user timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: But I tried replacing the url like "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.xml" not working either :(

Comment: Now it need authentication, so you have to use twitter oauth library for getting result. here is link for twitter console, [  https://dev.twitter.com/console ]. here you can see status/user_timeline will not return result without login

Comment: Can you explain a bit please. To be honest this is the first time I'm using API.

Comment: This is twitter oauth library, You have to use this library for getting your desired result [https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth]. Try this :)

Comment: I can't +1 as I don't have enough reputation :p

Comment: the library is so difficult for me. I've added an application, grabbed auth keys. Is there a way to use the code I posted just to grab the tweets.

Comment: @GokulGopalaKrishnan , I have code but it is difficult to share here bcoz of formatting time.:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32740/discussion-between-gokul-gopala-krishnan-and-jay-hardia)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because your using a deprecated API. below is the output from the feed.

```
<errors>
<error code="68">
The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.
</error>
</errors>
```

Comment: Thanks @DevZer0 
Actually I know this, but I can't find the updated API. In all tutorials I've seen they have this API only. Do you know the latest API url. By the way I'll change the Title because I fixed the 500 Server error

Comment: it will be json api, `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?username=` and xml `http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=`

Comment: I tried this but this is not working @JayHardia said it needs authentication, but actually I don't know how to perform that API call. can you explain if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The script you have uses Twitter API 1.0 and is no longer active.

I personally think the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview) is terrible, and I suggest you read [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314662/1438393).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll come again if I need a help.

Comment: I followed the steps in that post. Created an application, gor the auth keys. But is there a way to use the same code I posted above with the auth keys to grab the feed. I tried to modify the code on that post, but it' not working