# Twitter search for hashtags that date back almost 2 years

Tags: search, twitter

I am trying to retrieve all tweets with a certain #hashtag in them over a certain time period (dates 2 years back). Is there a way to automatically collect/save all the tweets concerned or the search results?

I tried scrolling down to that point, which kind of worked, but it took hours of holding the "page down-button".

Comment: **Alexander** - If my answer helped, could you 'tick' it as correct? Else I'll delete... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the twitter-api, it looks like you're trying to use the [search call](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

The two date methods (year-month-day) are:

- `hashtag since:2011-05-09` - Searches for "hashtag" and sent *since* date "2011-05-09".
- `hashtag until:2011-05-09` - Searches for "hashtag" and sent *before* date "2011-05-09".

Using these in the `GET` request, you can pull as many as the api allows at once, then loop through them and save them how you wish. You haven't provided a language that you're using, so this generic information is as far as I can help with.

Comment: Hey Jimbo, I'm kind of new to all this Twitter API using. Thank you so much for your answer. I was trying a problem-centered approach and it seems there is a solution to my "problem". Would you suggest a certain language? As i said I'm new to all of this and only have some experience in programming with "ruby".

Comment: I am totally biased toward PHP as a language to do this, because it's really simple to get to grips with. I wrote [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) as an explanation and library. However, if you already have programming experience with Ruby, you should check out the [twitter libraries page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) - ruby libraries are half way down there. Do what you're most comfortable with.

Comment: On the site for the "call"-operation it says: "The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.
You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week." Is that true or is it really possible to get the results for tweets or hashtag-results way back?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case when they have the date methods above. It's worth a try! :)