# migrating twitter api1.0 to 1.1 json data access issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, twitter

TWITTER changing api create problem in my mobile app contain twitter feed ,
My issue is: 
responseData is not parsing properly by EXT JS.
here  www.jsfiddle.net/9kSBz old code(working)
it is my code for TWITTER API 1

i got the data in JSON and  i access all data using

DATA.RESULTS
this works fine before realizing of twitter rest API 1.1
but its not working with new twitter api

my code for 1.1 is www.jsfiddle.net/HbEuL/1/" 
the same this i use in twitter api 1.1 its not working,
so how can i deal with this data..
i use php for OAuth twitter.
***Note: code is not full its for understand the my issue

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9kSBz [working code(old api)] & not working with new api here[http://www.jsfiddle.net/HbEuL/1/]

Comment: Umesh, have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make requests to the new twitter 1.1 API using client-side code any more. The **only** client-side stuff you can do is with basic **[widgets](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new)**.

You need to make **authenticated requests**, using a **server-side** language now. This is a limitation and choice of the new v1.1 API, and also you'll only be able to get results in **json**, no more xml / rss.

The issue isn't with your code, it's with the twitter API - you need authenticated requests (OAuth).

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) for, if you were using PHP as your server-side language of choice, the steps required to make authenticated requests over cURL.

Comment: ya jimbo , i read your answer thanx for helping but i need for mobile app , so i try other way and it works. thanx.