# Twitter feed on website

Tags: twitter, feed

I have a website with 3 sub pages. These 3 sub pages are information pages about 3 persons. What is the easiest way to give every page a dynamic twitter feed, linked to that person?

All I can find on the web are static feeds, just for 1 person.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Twitter recently announced [New feature: Dynamic timeline selection for embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18411). This may help you.

Comment: Jayce - If my answer helped, could you 'tick' it as correct on the left please? Else I'll delete... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the **only** thing you can / should do with client-side code for the new v1.1 API is: show a timeline using a widget.

Using this widget, if you choose the "search" option, you can construct a search query using your requirements to achieve the desired result.

Head to the [create a search widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/search) page, and here enter the following query:

```
from:user1+OR+from:user2
```

This'll give you a feed for multiple people.

**However**, if you want to do this *dynamically*, you can't use a widget and you will need to be using a **server-side language** (like PHP) to get the data you require.

If you choose PHP, [here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) a lot of people have found useful, step-by-step with pictures, on how to make authenticated requests to the twitter 1.1 API.

You'll want to be using the endpoint: [tweets/search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) with the previously mentioned query as `?q=from:user1+OR+from:user2`.

This way, you can inject the username into the query dynamically within your PHP code before shooting off the request - how you perform this architecturally is entirely up to you, but the above post and [library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) are a great start.