# Get RSS feed of a Twitter hashtag

Tags: twitter, rss

A client of mine wants to get an RSS feed for a twitter hashtag and include it in a list of other feeds from a variety of other sites.

I've Googled it all morning and I get a mix of answers. Some say it's possible, others say not anymore.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of the API v1.1 upgrade on June 11th 2013, twitter now only gives responses in JSON. You can view the official announcement [here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api).

That being said, I think you may need to think broader with your google searching ;)

Within 30 seconds, I found this, and it looks like exactly what you're looking for:

> RSS readers cannot subscribe to JSON feeds. twitter-json-to-rss is a set of PHP scripts that you install on your public facing server that allows you to get around this problem.

[Heres the library](https://github.com/thomasyung/twitter-json-to-rss). Note this is entirely untested by myself, so you'll have to check it out.

Basically, you need to send an authenticated request to the twitter 1.1 API, get your data, *then* convert the returned json to RSS for your client.

If you're using PHP, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662) is the fastest post to help you get up to speed with requests to the 1.1 API in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible anymore. Twitter removed RSS feeds from their data formats and will require you to use their API to achieve that.

Comment: This is not helpful - you could have at least suggested an alternative.

Comment: Well, the alternative is either to use Twitter's API, or to not rely on Twitter data. Superfeedr has a feature called "track" which will allow you to do that accross RSS feeds.

Comment: This is useful and interesting - you should append these to your answer :)