# Javascript type error: oauth is not a contructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, oauth

I am trying to use oauth to make twitter requests from jquery ajax. I have this so far, but I get the javascript error

```
TypeError: OAuth is not a constructor
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0-beta1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="oauth.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {

        var oauth = new OAuth(
            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "some token",
            "some token",
            '1.0A',
            null,
            'HMAC-SHA1'
        );

        oauth.get(
            "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977",
            "some token", 
            //you can get it at dev.twitter.com for your own apps
            "some token", 
            //you can get it at dev.twitter.com for your own apps
            function (e, data, res) {
                if (e) console.error(e);        
                console.log(require('util').inspect(data));
                done();      
            }
        ); 
    });





</script>

</head>

    <body>




    </body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Here is the source for oauth.js
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear you're using the library correctly.  `OAuth` is an object literal, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you´re using the new keyword when you don´t need it. As far as I have seen, after including that library you have the oauth object available globally. So not need to redefine oauth in your code. Check in the chrome console typing "oauth", it should be autocompleted and if press enter you´ll see the whole object.

In the other hand it doesn´t seem that oauth has a get method.

But if it have it you should use it like this: oauth.get(params)

Sorry for not helping more, but I don't know the library, what is pointed out it's just js concepts.

Regards,

Guillermo

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your website on a PHP server I would suggest you use this method [Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

If you can not use the PHP method still check out this post as it explans how to make your Twitter application that you will need to get your oauth_access token and oauth_access_token_secrete and you consumer_key and consumer_secrete.

Hope this helps.