# Twitter API 1.1 Hashtag Count

Tags: api, twitter, hashtag

I am having an issue figuring out how to return a total count for the number of times a hashtag was used on Twitter.  In the past I used the following code which did work but the "http://search.twitter.com/search.json" address has since been retired by Twitter.  The old code was:

```
<?php
   global $total, $hashtag;
   //$hashtag = '#supportvisitbogor2011';
   $hashtag = '#MyHashtag';
   $total = 0;
   function getTweets($hash_tag, $page) {
      global $total, $hashtag;
      $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&';
      $url .= 'page='.$page;    
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $json = curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);
      //echo "<pre>";    
      //$json_decode = json_decode($json);
      //print_r($json_decode->results);

      $json_decode = json_decode($json);        
      $total += count($json_decode->results);    
      if($json_decode->next_page){
         $temp = explode("&",$json_decode->next_page);        
         $p = explode("=",$temp[0]);                
         getTweets($hashtag,$p[1]);
      }        
   }

   getTweets($hashtag,1);

   echo $total; 
?>
```

I know that you know have to use a authorized twitter application and have access to be able to pull data.  I was able to set up the app and I can pull a list of data using the following code but I'm not sure how to use that data to come up with a total count.  Can someone help me to get a total by either changing the code I have or helping me with how I should go about it.  Here's the code I have that pulls the hashtag data:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$hashtag = "MyHashtag";
$consumerkey = "MYINFOWOULDBEHERE";
$consumersecret = "MYINFOWOULDBEHERE";
$accesstoken = "MYINFOWOULDBEHERE";
$accesstokensecret = "MYINFOWOULDBEHERE";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=".$hashtag);

echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example for Twitter 1.1 API made from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1). Keep this in mind:

> Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the
>   Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. **Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available** via the search interface.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

1. Download [twitter-api-php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and extract it to your folder at your server
2. [Create a Developer Account  and an Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314662/2824854)
3. Create a file `twitter_search.php` (in the same folder where you have *twitter-api-php*)
4. Add your tokens and keys to `twitter_search.php`

twitter_search.php:

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
    'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
    'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
);

/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$hashtag = 'twitterapi';
$getfield = '?q=%23'.$hashtag.'&result_type=recent&include_entities=true&count=100';

// Perform the request
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json_output = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();

// Let's calculate how many results we got
$json = json_decode($json_output);
$n = count($json->statuses);
echo $n;
?>
```

[Using the Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

[I posted originally this example in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175733/display-number-of-tweets-on-a-hashtag/19178263#19178263)