# Twitter read error

Tags: php, twitter

this is the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/razefm.xml?count=4): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 410 Gone in /home/tweets.php on line 44

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/razefm.xml?count=4" in /home/tweets.php on line 44
```

What I have on line 44 is:

```
$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.xml?count=4";
$feed   = simplexml_load_file($url); <--- Line 44
```

I know twitter made some recent changes to it's API, but for some reason, I don't know what it is that I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

This is what I have on my index:

```
<?php
          $username = "razefm";//your twitter username
          $number = 4;//number of tweets
          include ("{$dir}/php/tweets.php");
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you point your browser to the URL in your first error message, you'll see this message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1."

In brief: You'll need a Twitter developer account, an "App" in Twitter, and your PHP must be changed to read a response coming in JSON, not in XML.

For more details, have a look at this question: [Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1?lq=1).

But maybe what you want is just an [Embedded Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) that directly puts your tweets (with the possibility to reply and all) on a web page? In your Twitter account settings, you can create a Widget for this. Set the options and copy & paste the HTML code on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter   API v1 is no longer active. you will need to move on to new API (v 1.1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for really simple Twitter library I recommend mine https://github.com/vojant/Twitter-php

Ofcourse you have to create Twitter application to interact with Twitter api, you can do it here: https://dev.twitter.com/apps

**If you want to read user's timeline here's example:**

```
$consumerKey = YOUR TWITTER CONSUMER KEY
$consumerSecret = YOUR TWITTER CONSUMER SECRET
$accessToken = YOUR TWITTER ACCESS TOKEN
$accessTokenSecret = YOUR TWITTER ACCESS TOKE SECRET

//Name of Twitter user
$userName = '';

$twitter = new \TwitterPhp\RestApi($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$accessToken,$accessTokenSecret);
$connectionUser = $twitter->connectAsUser();
$connectionUser->get('statuses/user_timeline',array('screen_name' => $userName));
```