# Twitter 1.1 javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

We were using Twitter v1 to embed our latest tweets into our website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/[handle].json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=2"></script>
```

I understand that we have to use v1.1 now

> {"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}

I have set up all the api and auth keys but I am not going to use the [php example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1)

Is it possible to just replace the current javascript with a new one using something from the 1.1 api.

All we really need is to embed the latest 3 tweets.

Comment: You can find the current API over at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1 – the specific one you're asking for is [available here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline). Do you have any concrete questions regarding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1.1, calls to user timeline need to be authenticated. But Twitter has devised an simple process to create a client side embedded timeline.  It requires creating a widget through the settings page.  Here are the instructions:

[Creating an Embeddable Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#creating)

---

You can further customize the look of the widget on the client side by changing any one of client side options:

[Client Side Options](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#options)

---

To get the latest 3 tweets, make sure to set your tweet limit to 3.  It would look similiar to this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE" data-chrome="nofooter" data-tweet-limit="3">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```