# Twitter consumer key wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I am trying to get Twitter consumer key for a wordpress website. I understand I have to create an application, but want to be sure this is not going to affect my client's twitter account. I just simply want to get a twitter count for her website so I guess I don't understand why I have to create an application? Can anyone enlighten me? What is the purpose of the application? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly related to WordPress. Creating a Twittter application won't affect your account. You just gotta be careful not to share the secret keys.

Here's a very thorough answer about using the new Twitter 1.1 API

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

If you check the documentation the Get Users method returns the number of followers:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just careful when I go messing with my client's accounts. I don't really want an app only need to retrieve the keys so I guess I just make up some dummy information? I'll give it a go. Thanks again!