# get tweets using stream API twitter using 1.1

Tags: twitter, tweets, tweetstream

I found that we can use stream API to get the latest tweets based on hash tags or keywords.

It says you have to keep your http connection open. I am having a doubt regarding this.

Can anyone give me an example of stream API in php?

And other thing can I skip hashtag and keyword parameter is this API ? So I can all the statuses?

Can I pass a parameter like latitude and longitude to get tweets from the specific region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request tweets by location, see their API documentation for specifying location boundaries:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations

Comment: will this fetch me latest tweets or tweets in order how it's done?

Comment: i believe it gives latest tweets that match the boundaries you specify, ordered by newest first. it won't return retweets or tweets from protected users.

Comment: Thanks for this. do u have any example for this because stream API is different than others. and i haven't used stream API ever?

Comment: This looks to be a very simple example which you can expand upon, and adjust the query to include location parameters as per the API documentation :)

http://code.skyrocket.be/post/19736067936/consuming-the-twitter-streaming-api-with-php

Comment: Yes Even I found this but they seems to use API 1.0 which is deprecated now. So now it would be totally different process for this.

Comment: Yeh API 1.1 requires that you register as a developer (free) and get access keys, and use oAuth to authorize the API calls.  There's alot of good information on how this is done here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1  :)

Comment: I am using this example http://mikepultz.com/2013/06/mining-twitter-api-v1-1-streams-from-php-with-oauth/ It's working but what should I change to make it work with location API ? I tried to add location parameter but it give authentication error.