# Twitter API tweets

Tags: php, html, css

I do know about the whole deprecated version of their API. I hate it, but I was following this:

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

and I got the keys working, and followed the stuff.

On the index page, it shows this:

[image]

How can I get inside and customize how my tweets look? Stupid question, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Convert response to json, use php `json_encode()`, and print in your html with Jquery `$.each`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert response to json
2. replace url with expanded_url in message text
3. print in your html with Jquery $.each