# Unity3d Webplayer using Twitter: crossdomain request blocked

Tags: twitter, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml

In **Unity 3D** I use the WWW class to search on twitter. It works well on PC and Android, but it **fails in WebPlayer** because of it's [security sandbox](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html).

I tried

-htaccess rewrite rules: no success

-PHP proxy from my server to https://api.twitter.com: no success

It is not trivial, because twitter now needs special headers for authorization.
How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now I've a solution.

I partially rewrote the twitter request in PHP based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1).

The logic runs like this:
if WebPlayer:
  call PHP wrapper
else:
  process twitter request in Unity3D

Twitter introduced a few restrictions lately and this makes developers life harder.