# Twitter api request

Tags: twitter

I have read the documentation of twitter , and created an app and have all the keys needed .

Now i am trying to understand that simple one line http request ,to get a user latest twits .
I have read this [Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

but there is not one line code in there to make the request ( i don't know java script).

so , i have this :

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

Which will not work because my keys should be in this line, but i don't understand how to add them?? where and how i add my keys to this ?

Answer (score 0):

This url is like a node or address so twitter server knows what kind of request you need.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

Beside url you can pass many other parameter using http header, which is best to be used with server langunge programming, e.g PHP.
In PHP you can pass your credentials by changing header. While current twitter API are using Oauth, it's going to difficult to learn using Oauth this way, the easiest option is to use others' library. Check out 'twitter API library' (just google it)