# Extraction Twitter user's Bio and collect user following

Tags: twitter, text-extraction, feature-extraction, information-extraction

Does anyone know on how to extract Twitter user's bio and collect user following in twitter; Are there any tools for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the description of the user, twetts, followers, etc, firts: you need create a twitter app, then you have to consume the REST SERVICE from twitter ... the official info: [link](http://dev.twitter.com/). for this you can use (for example) php,java, c# or vb.net(etc) with OAUTH to consume data from twitter. You can review this topic to guide you a little [So you want to use the Twitter v1.1 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1) Greetings