# PHP Twitter Search API (using J7mbo's twitter-api-php)

Tags: php, api, search, curl, twitter

I'm tying to use J7mbo's [twitter-api-php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) to search for tweets with certain keywords. But every time I run my code, I get

`{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

I tried to run the example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#12939923) and it works fine with getting the user's timeline. Also tried running my search on the command line using the Twitter's signature generator and everything works fine with my keys and tokens.

That authentication error occurs when I run the following code

```
$settings = array(
    'consumer_key' => '...',
    'consumer_secret' => '...',
    'oauth_access_token' => '...',
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => '...'
);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$fields = '?q=twitter';
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($fields)->buildOauth($url, 'GET')
                ->performRequest();
```

As I looked into the code in`TwitterAPIExchange` class and in the example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#12939923), it seems that when the query parameters is appended to `CURLOPT_URL`, the error would appear. But I don't know if that's really the reason, neither how to fix it if that's the case. Any help for this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I also need to add the parameters for GET into the `$oauth` array in the code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#12939923) and authenticate using that. Though, I still can't get J7mbo's code working.