# Get the ID direct message twitter for api data

Tags: php, api, twitter

Im writing a script for retrieving the twitter status from ID.
To get the id from the public tweets is not my problem.
I cannot find the ID from a Direct Message or dm conversation.

**Twitter API documentation:**

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages/show

```
GET direct_messages/show
```

Returns a single direct message, specified by an **id parameter**. Like the /1.1/direct_messages.format request, this method will include the user objects of the sender and recipient

Does anybody knows how to get the Id parameter from a Direct Message to construct a request for the api?

The script for getting the data is documented here and is working nicely.

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662)

Example Request
GET

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/show.json?id=240136858829479936
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to select the direct message you want from some kind of list or overview. For example using the [`direct_messages` call](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages)