# Twitter API not asking for user access permission

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am a newbie using twitter API and trying to fetch the user's timeline posts using the twitter API. I have tries this piece of code to achieve this.

It is showing me all my account's timeline data but not asking for user permission access or login credentials as technically i am not logged into my account right now still it is showing me all my account's data.

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"; 
$oauth_access_token = "ACCESS TOKEN";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "ACCESS TOKEN SECRET";
$consumer_key = "APP KEY";
$consumer_secret = "APP KEY SECRET";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make requests
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);

//print it out
echo "<pre>"; print_r ($twitter_data);
```

I have found the code on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1#answer-12939923)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the Access Token and Access Token Secret *for your account* that you got from your Twitter Application Settings page, so you are already logged in. That is all the user authentication data you need to access *your* account through API.

Only for reading someone else's protected data you'll need access token and secret *for their account*, which you can obtain by implementing Twitter OAuth login flow (redirecting them to twitter and asking them to grant your app, access to their account).