# Get latest Tweets - What API

Tags: php, twitter

I know this has been discussed a lot here, but I still don't seem able to find aworking solution. Either it's out of date, it's the wrong programming-language or it's no longer supported.

All I want to do is: Get the last 'n' tweets from a public Twitter profile using PHP/JavaScript.

What API should I use best?
How do I keep it as lightweight as possible?
I can't use Node. js

I tried this, but I can't seem to get it to work, as simple as it may look like.
[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

I've already registered for a developer account and created a "Twitter-App".

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction; spacing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) API, which I have used once and it works perfectly.

Download the file `TwitterApiExchange.php` from the repository above and you may use the following sample code to fetch tweets of a user:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$user = "rootcss";
$count = 100;

if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
  $user = $_GET['user'];
}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
  $count = $_GET['count'];
}

$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(), $assoc = TRUE);

if (isset($string["errors"][0]["message"])) {
  echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>" . $string['errors'][0]["message"] . "</em></p>";
  exit();
}
foreach ($string as $items) {
  echo "Time and Date of Tweet: " . $items['created_at'] . "<br />";
  echo "Tweet: " . $items['text'] . "<br />";
  echo "Tweeted by: " . $items['user']['name'] . "<br />";
  echo "Screen name: " . $items['user']['screen_name'] . "<br />";
  echo "Followers: " . $items['user']['followers_count'] . "<br />";
  echo "Friends: " . $items['user']['friends_count'] . "<br />";
  echo "Listed: " . $items['user']['listed_count'] . "<br /><hr />";
}

echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It worked perfectly for me, Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: hi i am facing an issue with this..
i have implemented it in the laravel code but its getting tweets of wasim sadiq i just update the keys but its still getting the tweets of one person only