# Twitter JS API, update status

Tags: javascript, php, api, twitter

I'm at a total loss here. I believe I'm right in thinking there is no longer any JS API for twitter which just sucks hugely.

However I realise looking at this I could just use ajax and react to the responses from this:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

> OAuth Signature Generator
>
> Example Request POST
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk

However when I post to that url I get the following:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bad Authentication data` -> this is very self explanatory: Your Authentication is Bad; in other word, you are not authorized to use that API method.

Since you use `POST` method, make sure you set your APP access level to `Read & Write`.

Sign in to [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com), and in the Applications Management page for your app, click the Permissions tab. There you can change your access level.

For further reading, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314662/4262684).