# Can't get Twitter Widget working

Tags: php, api, twitter, widget

I wondered if someone can help?

I've purchased a web theme for a client but can't get the twitter widget working. It's probably something really simple but as I'm not a web developer I'm struggling to figure out what's preventing it form working.

Here's the webpage http://www.blackrocksearch.co.uk/new/ - the twitter feed should display in the footer. It works on the templates demo site but I notice in the item comments other customers having the same issue so think there could be a glitch somewhere.

Demo where it's working here:http://vasterad.com/themes/sensation/index.html

Here's the snippet of code from the twitter.php file which is apparently the only area I need to configure (I've left out the actual access token numbers for security):

```
    <?php

/**
* Usage:
* Send the url you want to access url encoded in the url paramater, for example (This is with JS):
* /twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent('statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=MikeRogers0&count=2')
*/

// The tokens, keys and secrets from the app you created at https://dev.twitter.com/apps
$config = array(
'oauth_access_token' => 'token-here',
'oauth_access_token_secret' => 'token-here',
'consumer_key' => 'token-here',
'consumer_secret' => 'token-here',
'use_whitelist' => true, // If you want to only allow some requests to use this script.
'base_url' => 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
);

/*
* Ok, no more config should really be needed. Yay!
*/

// We'll get the URL from $_GET[]. Make sure the url is url encoded, for example encodeURIComponent('statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=MikeRogers0&count=10&include_rts=false&exclude_replies=true')
if(!isset($_GET['url'])){
die('No URL set');
}

$url = $_GET['url'];


if($config['use_whitelist'] && !isset($whitelist[$url])){
die('URL is not authorised');
}

// Figure out the URL parmaters
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $url_arguments);

$full_url = $config['base_url'].$url; // Url with the query on it.
$base_url = $config['base_url'].$url_parts['path']; // Url with the query.

/**
* Code below from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1 by Rivers
* with a few modfications by Mike Rogers to support variables in the URL nicely
*/

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
$r = array();
ksort($params);
foreach($params as $key=>$value){
$r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
}
return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
$r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
$values = array();
foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
$values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
$r .= implode(', ', $values);
return $r;
}

// Set up the oauth Authorization array
$oauth = array(
'oauth_consumer_key' => $config['consumer_key'],
'oauth_nonce' => time(),
'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
'oauth_token' => $config['oauth_access_token'],
'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);
$base_info = buildBaseString($base_url, 'GET', array_merge($oauth, $url_arguments));
$composite_key = rawurlencode($config['consumer_secret']) . '&' . rawurlencode($config['oauth_access_token_secret']);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

// Make Requests
$header = array(
buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth),
'Expect:'
);
$options = array(
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_URL => $full_url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$result = curl_exec($feed);
$info = curl_getinfo($feed);
curl_close($feed);

// Send suitable headers to the end user.
if(isset($info['content_type']) && isset($info['size_download'])){
header('Content-Type: '.$info['content_type']);
header('Content-Length: '.$info['size_download']);

}

echo($result);
?>
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: That snippet ain't helping so much. A configuration file doesn't do anything but defining. What's twitter oauth library you're using? Is that bundled with the theme you've bought? Either to set `user_whitelist` to `false` or show more code of those twitter thingy code

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chay22!

How do I find out which twitter oauth library the theme uses?

Comment: I've updated the twitter.php snippet of code above to show the complete file. Hope that helps work out what the issue might be!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking on your site on [PHP file that doing a request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG6u4.png) to Twitter's response, it appears that your request needs to do a secure connection. So, my guesses are:

#### 1. Connecting through https

Change your `base_url` key on `$config` variable to https.

```
$config = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => 'token-here',
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => 'token-here',
    'consumer_key' => 'token-here',
    'consumer_secret' => 'token-here',
    'use_whitelist' => true,
    'base_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/' //was http://api.twitter.com/1.1/
);
```

#### 2. Adding CA (Certificate Authority) cert file

In case my first guess doesn't resolve anything, adding CA cert on cURL request might help. First, get your own [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem). Save it on some path you could recognize. Then simply set cURL option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`to true and optionally you can also explicitly set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to its default value which is 2.

In example, according to your snippet, saving in a same path as your Twitter cURL PHP file.

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => __DIR__ . '/cacert.pem', //or dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem' for PHP < 5.3
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $full_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
);
```

As an option you can also predefine the cacert.pem in your php.ini configuration file. Just add/edit following line and don't forget about the path too

```
curl.cainfo = "some/path/cacert.pem"
```

Let me know

Comment: Thanks so much you're a star! Simply changing it to a secure connection has worked!