# Simple GET request with Twitter API in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-rest-api

Does anyone know how to do a simple GET request of a user's timeline using the Twitter API in iOS?
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

I realize there are multiple frameworks out there but this is all I need and would prefer not to use them just for this.  I also don't want to use the Social framework on iOS because it requires the user to have a Twitter account.

I've implemented this in PHP from this post here but not sure how to do the equivalent thing in iOS.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12939923/284714

Comment: You didn't mention anything about Fabric. So I would like to know if you have tried to use Fabric for iOS from Twitter or not https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/overview.html ? Fabric can help you install Twitter SDK to your project and then you can use this example to From Twitter https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/access-rest-api.html#construct-a-twitter-request-manually to do GET Requests

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of Fabric but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Ok, No problem. By the way, if you create a twitter app here https://apps.twitter.com and get the access/secret key. You can use them to remove the restriction of requiring the user to have a twitter account as you mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it with NSURLSession, which is the current, modern, "future proof" (lol) way of doing it on iOS/macOS:

```
NSURLSession *urlSession;
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask;
NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
dataTask = [urlSession
            dataTaskWithURL:twitterURL
            completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                // add error checking here
                NSLog(@"Got %lu bytes of data from twitter", (unsigned long)[data length]);

            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

And if swift is your cup of tea:

```
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
let url: URL! = URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json");
dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) {
    (data, response, error) in
    // check errors and stuff.
    print(data)
}
dataTask?.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. it would be awesome if you can include the swift version too

Comment: @Suhaib dang it I knew somebody was going to ask for that :)  I added a swift version.

Comment: This isn't something that can be done using a simple request.  They have to be authorized using OAuth.  This is the part I don't know how to implement in iOS.

Comment: this code gives bad authentication data error

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to do this on iOS would be to use the [ACAccountStore](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accounts/acaccountstore) class to get one of the user's authenticated Twitter accounts, then perform a request using [SLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/social/slrequest). SLRequest has an `account` property you'd use to include the account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I'm aware of that class but I don't want to require the user to have a Twitter account.

Comment: All Twitter API requests require account authentication as of API v1.1

Comment: Yes, I know but using ACAccountStore requires that the user themselves are signed in with a Twitter account.  I want to get tweets from an arbitrary timeline without requiring the user to have a Twitter account.