# Fetching tweets on the basis of screen_name in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, twitter

I want to develop a website where user can write the twitter screen name of any celebrity so when click on show show tweet button it will show latest tweet of that screen_name.I want to implement it in angular and node js?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow some steps that I will list to do so. Firstly [create your developer account in twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314662/6880789). After that there is a library for this in Node, you can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter).

Below code shows a route in your application which can used to get recent twits.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var Twitter = require('twitter');

    var app = express();

    var client = new Twitter({
      consumer_key: 'your-key',
      consumer_secret: 'your-key',
      access_token_key: 'your-key',
      access_token_secret: 'your-key'
    });



    app.get('/twitter/:screenname', function(req, res, next) {
        var params = {screen_name: req.params.screenname};
        client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
          if (!error) {
            return res.status(200).json({tweets});
          }
          return res.status(500).json({error});
        });
    }) 
    var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server running at port 3000')
    })
```