# Get Twitter Feed as JSON (tweeter scraper) with angular/node/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, twitter

I want to create dashboard having feed from twitter tweets in `angular2/node` platform , on googling i found

https://github.com/opensas/twitter-scraper

but after running this script i got error

> [ { code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.' } ] }

also i got this meaningful question in SO but this is using php

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12916539/5043867%27%27)

anyone can do this in nodeJs/angular ?

or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use phantomJs  or casperJs (install them with npm)  for scraping site but in this time some sites use distill-network to prevent or block scraping bot . 
in your problem you have two solution the clean and easy one :

- access tweeter RestAPI .
- if this not work with you . 
  you may try to scrape twitter with your twitter account you will entering your info in the header of your phantomjs bot then browse search page and fill the form with casperjs and submit it you can make this process dynamically and view the return data to store in db or view in node web app 
  here is an **example**  http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-to-twitter-using-casperjs-and-phantomjs-and-extract-tweets/
  and https://gist.github.com/nwaomachux/35d1c424966fccd16ae1

Comment: thanku for the information, but i was looking for the working example like on plunker or somewhere else