# SSL certificate error using Twitter API

Tags: php, ssl

I'm developing locally on a Windows IIS server and trying to use the Twitter API in my application, like this:

```
$settings = array(
  'oauth_access_token' => "...",
  'oauth_access_token_secret' => "...",
  'consumer_key' => "...",
  'consumer_secret' => "..."
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$getfield = "?q=%23test";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Running this gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\...\vendor\j7mbo\twitter-api-php\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 321
>   Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\...\vendor\j7mbo\twitter-api-php\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 321

I have found out that you need to add a [SSL certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), I've downloaded the cacert.pem but I'm lost on how to enable it in IIS. Any pointers?

Edit: So I have now imported a certificate from our company in IIS, my server is now running on https. I added this to my `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\...\certificate.PFX"
```

But after restarting the server I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662 
 https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out all that hassle of installing our company's certificate was unneeded. I followed [these instructions](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) (thanks RamRaider) and it works. Hurrah \o/