# Authentication Problem when using Twitter API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, twitter, oauth

I have used **Firebase** to login to Twitter and generate `token` and `secret` that is needed auth in Twitter API (I think)

I have integrated Firebase with no errors and It works fine and returns both the values correctly.

> Now I don't know how to implement these value and pass this token in twitter API. Please help with this (Javascript/React)

My problem is exactly this [Same problem In PHP(from StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1) except I used React instead of PHP and i have trouble understanding PHP code and implementing that logic to Javascript.

I also tried sending API request via Postman but I don't what fails.[image: Postman API request for Twitter]

Answer (score 1):

You must pass headers and choose authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-twitter-login`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-login) package to get all tokens automatically, or look on codebase of it:

- [signature.ts](https://github.com/alexandrtovmach/react-twitter-login/blob/master/src/services/signature.ts) - OAuth headers generation
- [oauth1](https://github.com/alexandrtovmach/react-twitter-login/blob/master/src/services/oauth1.ts) - OAuth 1.0 flow